# Importing a Type Library into your Component Palette using Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe6

I recently switched from Borland Delphi 7 to Embarcadero Delphi XE6 and I find it very difficult to install a library with components. I wish to install the Microsoft Speech Library.

I have searched on the web for tutorials and guides, but non of them have helped me.

Can someone please help me by giving a step by step tutorial. I asked two of my friends which also uses Delphi XE6 and they switched from Delphi 7 and Delph 2010. They also do not know how to do it.

Comment: If you mean how to import MS Speech Object Library, then go to menu *Component | Import Component...* There choose *Import a Type Library*, press *Next*, search for *Microsoft Speech Object Library* and finish the wizard checking the *Generate Component Wrappers* check box.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this area. You still do it the same way as in D7. How do you do it there?

Comment: @TLama has pointed out how to import type libraries. For installing other components, the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Install_Component) has this information. What part isn't clear?

Comment: Your question indicates some confusion. A 3rd-Party DLL is not a "component" to Delphi, and it doesn't come "with components". As stated above, you need to generate a Type Library for it, which is a Delphi wrapper generated by the IDE when you do the import (the TLB file) that lets you access the functions inside of the DLL. That part hasn't changed in ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have Delphi XE6 anymore. I'm now using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 1, but I did struggle to import a Type Library in XE6 as it was a bit different to Delphi 7. Anyway I can't remember how I managed to do it in XE6, but I'm assuming it is the same in Berlin. So here:

1. Go to 'Component' in the main menu.
2. Choose 'Import Component'.
3. Choose 'Import a Type Library' and click on Next.
4. Choose the library you wish to install.
5. Choose a name for it and where/how you want to install it.
6. Just follow the rest of the steps. It will then compile and install it into your IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that the type library importer in XE6 is broken.  I've found at least one instance where the resultant unit has several interfaces with the parameter declared incorrectly as a const type instead of a var type.  Delphi 2010 imports the same library correctly.